# Nested itemize don't show item label

Tags: formatting, itemize, nesting

I use these itemize:

```
\begin{itemize}
\item [\textbf{Home Page - Utente Semplice}]
 \begin{itemize}
    \item Sono presenti troppi contenuti poco utili (1-6-7);
    \item Il proprio avatar, non è un rimando efficace alla propria home page, dove non si vede il proprio profilo, ma i grafici del proprio impianto (1-7);
    \item Se si passa da utente semplice ad utente professionista, l'avatar non viene cambiato (7);
    \item Se si clicca sul proprio nome, si viene rimandati alla home page, mentre sarebbe più logico essere portati ai propri dati (1-3);
\end{itemize}
\item [\textbf{Home Page - Utente Professionista}] \begin{itemize}
    \item Sono presenti troppi contenuti poco utili (1-6-7);
    \item Se si passa da utente professionista ad utente semplice, l'avatar non viene cambiato (7);
    \item Se si clicca sul proprio nome, si viene rimandati alla home page, mentre sarebbe più logico essere portati ai propri dati (1-3);
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
```

The result is that:
[image]

As you can see, the labels of the items in the first itemize, aren't showed well (there isn't the first part of the words).

How can I fix that?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please show us a MWE instead of such a code snippet. Maybe you should try `enumitem` or use a `description` list instead of `itemize`.

Comment: @TeXnician description solves that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution, replacing the higher level itemize with `enumerate`, and using the `widest` key from `enumitem`.

However, I suggest using a `multiline` `description` environment, which might look better:

```
    \documentclass[italian]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{geometry}
    \usepackage{enumitem}
\newlength\descrwidth
    \begin{document}

\setlist[itemize, 1]{label=\textendash,wide=0.5em, leftmargin=*}
\begin{enumerate}[wide=0pt, leftmargin=*, widest=\textbf{Home Page – Utente Professionista}, font=\bfseries]
\item [Home Page – Utente Semplice]
 \begin{itemize}
    \item Sono presenti troppi contenuti poco utili (1-6-7);
    \item Il proprio avatar, non è un rimando efficace alla propria home page, dove non si vede il proprio profilo, ma i grafici del proprio impianto (1-7);
    \item Se si passa da utente semplice ad utente professionista, l'avatar non viene cambiato (7);
    \item Se si clicca sul proprio nome, si viene rimandati alla home page, mentre sarebbe più logico essere portati ai propri dati (1-3);
\end{itemize}
\item [Home Page – Utente Professionista] \begin{itemize}
    \item Sono presenti troppi contenuti poco utili (1-6-7);
    \item Se si passa da utente professionista ad utente semplice, l'avatar non viene cambiato (7);
    \item Se si clicca sul proprio nome, si viene rimandati alla home page, mentre sarebbe più logico essere portati ai propri dati (1-3);
\end{itemize}
\end{enumerate}

\settowidth{\descrwidth}{\textbf{Utente Professionista }}
\begin{description}[wide=0pt, style=multiline, leftmargin=\descrwidth]
\item [Home Page\\Utente Semplice]
 \begin{itemize}
    \item Sono presenti troppi contenuti poco utili (1-6-7); \the\descrwidth
    \item Il proprio avatar, non è un rimando efficace alla propria home page, dove non si vede il proprio profilo, ma i grafici del proprio impianto (1-7);
    \item Se si passa da utente semplice ad utente professionista, l'avatar non viene cambiato (7);
    \item Se si clicca sul proprio nome, si viene rimandati alla home page, mentre sarebbe più logico essere portati ai propri dati (1-3);
\end{itemize}
\item [Home Page \\Utente~Professionista] \begin{itemize}
    \item Sono presenti troppi contenuti poco utili (1-6-7);
    \item Se si passa da utente professionista ad utente semplice, l'avatar non viene cambiato (7);
    \item Se si clicca sul proprio nome, si viene rimandati alla home page, mentre sarebbe più logico essere portati ai propri dati (1-3);
\end{itemize}
\end{description}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is simple: Itemize expects circa one character as label and calculates its width to fit that. You might want to use a list environment that's specifically intended to provide support for long labels, namely `description`.

Another option would be to use `enumitem` (see the manual for more information) that can change many aspects of lists.